# How to add scroll bar for an item that is larger than the screen resolution in qml?

Tags: qt, scrollbar, screen, qml

I use `QtQuick 1.1` and I have an item like this below:

```
Item {
    id: myItem
    width: 12345
    height: 12345
    //...
}
```

When I run my qml project, it doesn't show any scroll bar for this item (horizental and vertical).

How can i add scroll bar to it? And if I use Qt and QML together (using a QWidget and QDeclarativeView on it), then what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Making UI using qml is kind of UI paradigm shift when compared to making desktop widgets. What you are expecting is a normal desktop widget behavior, which is absent in the most mobile platforms UIs. In them, *usually,* scroll bars are associated with the lists and not with complete pages.

You can however implement that in qml as well. You can have the top element as flickable instead of a rectangle, and the show the scroll bars yourself based on flicks on the page. Try to go through the qml RSSfeed example to understand how you can use combination of flickable and other elements to achieve this.

P.S. : Also, see the [qml desktop components](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/06/06/desktop-components-for-qt-5/) introduced in Qt5. They will give you the widget behavior. See if it fits what you want.

But again, you should ask yourself, what exactly are you trying to achieve here ?